# I am putting tons of names to XLS. need shortcuts to repeatedly type common names (Mary john Etc) to designated cell. i.e. alt+ctl M inserts MARY

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, keyboard-shortcuts

I am transcribing long handwritten lists of names to XLS files. I need a way to repeatedly insert common names such as Mary, John, etc.

For example, click <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> and shortcut will type MARY in the designated cell. I have Office 365. I have function names set up, for example `=m` will insert Mary. But if I then have to add Jane to make it Mary Jane it changes all the Marys to Mary Janes.

How can I do this in a way that does not replace all of these?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have `=m` in a lot of cells, just use Search & Replace to substitute those to `'Mary`
*(and similar / the same for other names)*.

Another way: Make your macro(s) **append** new names to the active cell,
*and then use shortcuts/hotkeys to run these macros*.

Similar to:
`ActiveCell.Text=ActiveCell.Text+" John"`

Comment: the answer cannot be macro, functions or autocorrect for various reasons too complicated to explain. i need a simple way to define for example ctl+alt M as "insert Mary."

Answer (score 0):

You can use AutoCorrect feature for this.

You can define your own entries e.g. `m` and its replacement word like `Mary`.

If you don't need autocorrect at the moment you can undo it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

See e.g. [Autocorrect in Excel](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/autocorrect-excel-use-customize-stop/)